# How to find index of a struct element as index of byte array in union (in standard C)

Tags: c

I define a struct and an union as below:

```
struct MY_STRUCT
{
    int a;
    unsigned int x;
    char c;
};

union MY_UNION
{
    unsigned char myByte[sizeof(struct MY_STRUCT)];
    struct MY_STRUCT myStruct;
};
```

How i find location (index) of `myStruct.x` in `myByte[]` array dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the initial byte of `myStrunct`and `myByte` have the same address, you can use [`offsetof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof) operator for that:

```
size_t offset = offsetof(MY_STRUCT, x);
MY_UNION u;
unsigned char *ptr = &u.myByte[offset];
```

Note that this is not done dynamically: `offsetof` is computed statically at compile time.